# PHP form seems to be sending empty POST data

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have been at this for quite some time now and I am one day from the psych ward.

There is a form located in a Profile page for updating user details. The form sends data to an update.php file that does the rest. The problem is no data ever arrives at the update.php script

This is the form

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>E-Mail</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" disabled="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Hobbies</label>

    <select class="form-control select-mini" name="hobby">
        <option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
        <option value="Jumping">Jumping</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>House Address</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $acc_no; ?>">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Update Account" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
</div>
</form>
```

This is the update.php script

```
<?php

require 'php_file.php';
print_r($_POST); // check if post data ever arrived. Guess what? It never did :(
if (
    !empty($_POST['hobby'])||
    !empty($_POST['address'])){

        $hobby = $_POST['hobby'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        //Do something else with post data

    }

?>
```

I've checked everything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the HTACCESS rules I had in place for hiding the .php extension of my scripts was the major culprit.

These rules below basically redirect all requests to their non .php versions.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

However I forgot they did their job exteremely well and redirected every request including form submissions. So it turns out when there is a redirect, the HTTP request method can change. In this case I sent a POST request with my form and my update.php script expected one. Only problem was by the time it got to the update.php script, It was a GET request.

[Cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) pointed this out and on checking the network tab on Firefox devtools I saw the 302 redirects.

**Solution:**  I simply changed my action from **update.php** to simply  **update**. That stopped any redirects and my POST data was finally sent across to my update.php script in peace.

Thanks to everybody in the comment section who said even a word and most importantly thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)

Comment: In you question you never stated that you use htaccess

Comment: @FridayAmeh That's specifically the whole point of the question. I never knew the htaccess redirects were manipulating my request's method. If I knew, I wouldn't have a question/problem to begin with